# How to select a few numbers from a given number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have entered a certain 4 digit number for example ,1234 how do I choose like the first 2 numbers or the last two numbers from the cell by that i mean suppose i want it to return 34 for the last two digits and I want it to return 12 for the first two digits. So anytime I change my 4 digit number it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions, e.g.

```
=LEFT("1234", 2)
=RIGHT("1234", 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 4-digit number is, in fact, a string you can parse the string as suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen. In my Excel 365, when I enter `1234` in a cell formatted as `General` I can use the same method.

```
=LEFT(A1, 2)
and
=Right(A1, 2)
```

However, this conversion of a number to text mustn't be presumed to work under all circumstances. Therefore you may prefer to convert the number to text explicitly in the formula.

```
=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0000"), 2)
and
=Right(TEXT(A1,"0000"), 2)
```

This method has the added advantage of being able to handle numbers of less than 4 digits.

On the other hand, you can also extract first and last digits from a true number, without converting it to text.

```
=INT(A1/100)
and
=MOD(A1,100)
```

The main difference is that the results are also numbers (all partial strings are text). Therefore this would be the preferred method if you don't want to worry about strings, text, numbers, numerics and cell formats.